# How to fit long time period data into Regression models in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, forecasting

I'm working on the regresion model with population and demand values my data is for period from 1980 to 2021 by country, below example where under year is the number of population and under year_dem is the demand for item.

[image]

Taks is to create prediction model to forecast demand for each country in future.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the dataset containing past data on vaccine demand and supply
data = df.iloc[0]
X = data.drop(['Country','ISO','1980_dem', '1981_dem', '1982_dem','1983_dem','1984_dem','1985_dem','1986_dem','1987_dem','1988_dem','1989_dem','1990_dem','1991_dem','1992_dem','1993_dem','1994_dem','1995_dem','1996_dem','1997_dem','1998_dem','1999_dem','2000_dem','2001_dem','2002_dem','2003_dem','2004_dem','2005_dem','2006_dem','2007_dem','2008_dem','2009_dem','2010_dem','2011_dem','2012_dem','2013_dem','2014_dem','2015_dem','2016_dem','2017_dem','2018_dem','2019_dem','2020_dem','2021_dem'])
y = data['1980_dem']

model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50, max_features="auto", random_state=44)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Split the DataFrame into a training set and a testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=44)

# Use the trained model to make predictions on the test set
#predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Calculate the accuracy of the predictions
#accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)
#print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy,2),'%.')
```

expect to have created a model with Accuracy printed and poisbilit to predict values for future based on the model.

Comment: I don't think RandomForestRegressor is designed for time series forecasting.

Comment: Hi PiotrK. I think this question is too open-ended to be answered definitively. Olivier Grisel [gave a tutorial](https://github.com/ogrisel/euroscipy-2022-time-series/blob/main/plot_time_series_feature_engineering.ipynb) at EuroSciPy on time-series forecasting that introduces some of the problems and how to approach them in scikit-learn.